# Submit a form with list of objects in Polymer

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I was wondering what is the best way to submit a form(`iron-form`) with the following structure:

Basic Polymer `iron-form` (starting point):

```
<form is="iron-form" method="post" action="/" id="basic">
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="addresses" items="[[addresses]]">
        <paper-input name="city" label="City" value="[[item.city]]"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="street" label="Street" value="[[item.street]]"></paper-input>
    </template>
</form>
```

Target JSON payload structure after submit:

```
addresses: [
    { city: "X", street: "X" },
    { city: "Y", street: "Y" }
]
```

The way I am doing it now is using the `dom-repeat`'s `index` and manually extending the payload at `iron-form-presubmit` phase. The idea behind this approach is coming from Spring-MVC where this is handled in a really neat way.

i.e.:

```
<form is="iron-form" method="post" action="/" id="basic">
    <template is="dom-repeat" id="addresses" items="[[addresses]]">
        <paper-input name="addresses[[[index]]].city" label="City" value="[[item.city]]"></paper-input>
        <paper-input name="addresses[[[index]]].street" label="Street" value="[[item.street]]"></paper-input>
    </template>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forms aren't really designed to produce structured data, but rather just a bunch of key-value pairs. You will most likely need to use a 3rd party JavaScript library to produce the desired JSON, along with the structured `name` property as you have shown in your last bit of code.